# Unsatisfied dependency Principal

Tags: java, security, authentication, jax-rs, quarkus

I'm trying to implement a quarkus-extension for authorization/authentication. I used the existing `quarkus-smallrye-jwt-abx`-extension as an example. Everything seems to work fine, except that I can not inject the `Principal`:

```java
    @Inject
    private Principal principal;
```

I'm getting

> Unsatisfied dependency for type java.security.Principal and qualifiers [@Default]

Injecting `SecurityContext` and getting the `Principal` from it works fine:

```java
    @Context
    private SecurityContext sec;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("test")
    public String test() {
        return sec.getUserPrincipal().getName();
    }
```

In `quarkus-smallrye-jwt-abx`-extension, there is a `PrincipalProducer`, which seems to produce the `Principal`. Is this really necessary? Isn't that provided by the security subsystem itself? It also provides `SecurityContext`; why shouldn't it provide `Principal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the current resteasy / CDI integration as we are not providing a default that is based on the JAX-RS SecurityContext. The quarkus-smallrye-jwt extension is providing a PrincipalProducer to override the default because it installs a Principal that is a subinterface of java.security.Principal. The current workaround would be to provide your own Principal producer.

There is a bug report for this:
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/2528

Answer (score -2):

Please check your Android Manifest,  this usually means you are using service not declared.

Go to Manifest and add

```
<uses android-permission = "Read External storage..... />
```

Hope that solves the problem coder

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not talking about Android, I'm talking about Quarkus.